# How to send from javascript to javascript .NET instance function in Blazor? (jsinterop, invokeMethodAsync, jsruntime)

Tags: .net, blazor

I have some javascript where I need to send a value to a javascript function that calls .NET function via invokeMethodAsync

so the simple javascript code to send value something like:

```
invokeJStoBlzr("sfsd");
```

then the JS function...

```
window.invokeJStoBlzr(val) = (dotNetHelper) => {            
  dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('JStoSrvCall', val);
};
```

but it doesn't seem to like window.invokeJStoBlzr(val) so I think it's a matter of syntax. Anyone know how to properly write that?

Blazor code is

```
private DotNetObjectReference<Index> objRef;


public async Task startAsyc()    {   //called when client side makes selection
   await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("invokeJStoBlzr", objRef);
}

[JSInvokable]
protected static void JStoSrvCall(string value)
{
  //do whatever
}
```

I basically need to pass a javascript value to that invokeJStoBlzr function, which then is received in JStoSrvCall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I basically need to pass a javascript value to that invokeJStoBlzr
> function, which then is received in JStoSrvCall

If you want to pass a value from JavaScript to C# then you could do something like this:

```
<button @onclick="() => StartAsyc()">Start</button>
<h1>@JSMessage</h1>

@code{
    private string JSMessage { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsyc()
    {   //called when client side makes selection
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("invokeJStoBlzr", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this),
            "The Value You want to Send to JS");
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void JStoSrvCall(string value)
    {
        JSMessage = value;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

and JavaScript code will look like this:

```
function invokeJStoBlzr(instance, val) {
    instance.invokeMethodAsync('JStoSrvCall', val);
};
```

Comment: ok thx. How come StateHasChanged() is needed in the JSInvokable? because it's coming from client I guess?

Comment: In the above case `StateHasChanged()` is not needed because `StateHasChanged()` method is automatically called after a UI event is triggered.

Comment: Also, you initiate on the button onclick, but I need to initiate via that JS function....so the javascript would be invokeJStoBlzr(objRef, "whatever");, but then how/when would the StartAsync method get called?

Comment: you can put the ``StartAsyc()` on `OnAfterRenderAsync()` method.

Comment: but then is it always listening the whole lifetime of the page being opened? And the invoke will work more than once? That is the proper way to do this?

Comment: you can do something like this : `protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!firstRender) return;
        await StartAsyc();
    }`

Comment: to be clear, I do want to be able to use the method more than once. Your override allows that?

Comment: from where you want to call the `StartAsync` method?

Comment: when a javascript variable changes. But it can/will happen several times as the user does stuff on the page.

Comment: you can call this method from the javascript, what was the issue?

Comment: I'm just asking if I can call the javascript method more than once if I move StartAsync to onafterrenderasync as you suggest

Comment: I haven't got the exact scenario, but I hope it'll work

Comment: ya it works, thx